# SQL query to get value based on some values in fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a table named generations the structure of the table is as follows

[image]

I want to get value 10 as output when ten_generation have value 1 otherwise it will not return any value, 20 as output if twenty_generation have value 1 otherwise it will not return any value, 30 as output if thirty_generation have value 1 otherwise it will not return any value. If all the three fields has a value 1 output will be 10,20,30 also the task_id will provided as the input.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.  Also, what does it return when all the conditions are true?

Comment: Please could you show examples and what results you expect.  Your statement is contradictory.  A logic table would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to **get** value..." - "get" how, exactly? You probably want to write a SELECT query. What should be in the output? The task_id, and then the same three columns, each showing 10 or 20 or 30 respectively, and NULL otherwise? Or what else?

Comment: @JeffUK for example if only twenty_generation contain value 1  the output is 20  and if twenty_generation and ten_generation contain value 1 output is 10,20

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: @ThorstenKettner MySql

Comment: Okay, I've tagged it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear what you intend the output to be when multiple generation columns are `1` but one solution is to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ten_generation    = 1 THEN 10
         WHEN twenty_generation = 1 THEN 20
         WHEN thirty_generation = 1 THEN 30
                                    ELSE NULL
       END AS value
FROM   generations
WHERE  id = :your_id
```

If you want it as multiple columns then:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ten_generation = 1
         THEN 10
         ELSE NULL
       END AS ten_value,
       CASE
         WHEN twenty_generation = 1
         THEN 20
         ELSE NULL
       END AS twenty_value,
       CASE
         WHEN thirty_generation = 1
         THEN 30
         ELSE NULL
       END AS thirty_value
FROM   generations
WHERE  id = :your_id
```

> if only twenty_generation contain value 1 the output is 20 and if twenty_generation and ten_generation contain value 1 output is 10,20

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         LEADING ',' FROM
         CASE WHEN ten_generation = 1 THEN '10' END
          || CASE WHEN twenty_generation = 1 THEN ',20' END
          || CASE WHEN thirty_generation = 1 THEN ',30' END
       ) AS value
FROM   generations
WHERE  id = :your_id
```

Comment: Assuming _generation columns are boolean, then in the latter example you don't need case statements you could just output ten_generation*10 as ten_value, twenty_generation*20 as twenty_value, etc

Comment: @JeffUK The problem is that it will return null if any of the field doesnt have value for example if  twenty_generation have no value it will return twenty_value as null

Comment: The stated requirement was "it will not return any value" which sounds like he wants null.  hard to be sure

Comment: @JeffUK In Oracle there is no such thing as an empty `VARCHAR2`, it is a `NULL` instead - so the Oracle query will return `NULL` if no values are "true".

Comment: In my opinion, returning `NULL` matches the request to "not return any value"  he doesn't want "" he wants null. If OP had asked for Zero or Blank I would agree that `NULL` is a problem,  the later edits to the question nullify my response anyway.

Comment: @JeffUK The queries I posted all return `NULL` if the generation booleans are not `1` and you appear to be saying the same thing so I do not understand the point you are trying to make as you appear to be arguing for something I am already doing.

Comment: @MT0 I was arguing that instead of case statements you could use mathematical operations only.. other people took issue with them returning null...

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you'd use `CONCAT_WS`:

```
select
  concat_ws(',',
    case when ten_generation = 1 then '10' end,
    case when twenty_generation = 1 then '20' end,
    case when thirty_generation = 1 then '30' end
  ) as result
from mytable 
where task_id = 2;
```